# Angular 2+ Providers/Service on Parent or Child component?

Tags: dependency-injection, service, typescript, angular2

I have recently started diving deeper into Angular 7 (with Ionic 3) and I have written a lot of code so far, and I have child & parent component relationships - but never like this before. I am trying to write "good" Angular code.

The problem I am now facing is, the Providers...

My **Child Component** needs access to the `SettingsProvider` but so does the **Parent Component**. So my question is, should I inject the `SettingsProvider` in both the child's and the parent's constructor or should I only inject it into the parent, and then pass it into the child via the `@Input` ???

Answer (score 3):

I would inject it into both. That way the Child Component gets the `SettingsProvider` in a single place. If the Child component is used in multiple places, it doesn't need to be wired up to the `SettingsProvider` in every place.

Comment: so what's the convention basically? what's considered best practice?

Comment: I'd like to be more consistent in the future